# Swift scroller is showing but not working

Tags: swift, uiscrollview

I have a Swift code

```
background_img_view.addSubview(background_image)
background_img_view.addSubview(usn)
profile_view.addSubview(PostsDiv)
profile_view.addSubview(PostDiv)
var scrollView: UIScrollView!
scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: view.bounds)
scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 1500)
scrollView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleHeight
scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
scrollView.addSubview(profile_view)
view.addSubview(background_img_view)
view.addSubview(scrollView)
```

I tested this on my phone and scroll bar is showing, but when i scroll nothing changes, also i can't click on anything on the screen . 
Full code http://pastebin.com/EXQeGMJ6

Comment: If you are adding scrollView in viewDidLoad(), the why don't you add it in the storyboard? It will save writing that much code in your file.

Comment: @PGDev i tried adding scroll view in story board but it didn't work

Comment: do it like here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LhhW3xqhCzg

Comment: @Kingalione my whole code is written programmatically so i can't do like him

Comment: well, in this case you have to code the constraints from the video also programatically. I think thats the problem here. You have no constraints on the scrollview.

Comment: @Kingalione i added constrains(0 from each side) to scroll view,but still the same result